# Problem with single quotes in man pages

Tags: mac, debian, xterm, manpages

When I ssh into my Debian Lenny server and open a man page, single quotes appear to be messed up. Example from the man page of apt-get:

> If no package matches the given
>   expression and the expression contains
>   one of    Â´.Â´, Â´?Â´ or Â´*Â´ then
>   it is assumed to be a POSIX regular
>   expression, and it is    applied to
>   all package names in the database. Any
>   matches are then installed (or
>   removed). Note that matching is done
>   by substring so Â´lo.*Â´ matches
>   Â´how-loÂ´ and    Â´lowestÂ´. If this
>   is undesired, anchor the regular
>   expression with a Â´^Â´ or Â´$Â´
>   character, or create a more specific
>   regular expression.

I'm on Mac OS X and using xterm. If I use Terminal, the problem doesn't happen.

My locale is configured correctly as far as I can see:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

The problem doesn't happen locally. Displaying man pages via xterm on Mac OS X works just fine.

I don't have any special configuration files for xterm. I'm using the default settings.

I'm not sure what's wrong with my environment, and I have no idea what to check next. I'd appreciate help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue by adding the following to my .bash_profile in Mac OS X:

```
export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
```